# How to integrate a heater in polyeurethane foam?

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, industrial-engineering

We are trying to integrate a heater in polyeurethane mattresses. However, the heating units we found are in fabric shape and hence the moment we pressurize the PE foam in the mold they deform and do not give even heating everywhere.

Therefore, we thought of making the PE mattress in 2 pieces and then sandwich the heater in between and then glue the two PE pieces together but maybe that would introduce wear and tear to the mattresses too early.

Any suggestions or methods would be great.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a consultant, and that service costs money.

Comment: True. But there are people out there that do it for good and not ONLY money. Plus uts not a million dollar idea. People who have the minimum experience in DIY projects might have a good idea. Yet, some people out there give Billion dollar ideas for good NOT ONLY money...

Comment: seems easier to put it in a mattress pad.  Putting a heater inside an insulator seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @TigerGuy thanks for the answer. Actually we only need to make the mattress warm so we do not need direct heating. Think of a heated sofa. Plus, our PE is just plane PE not multiple layers or materials. Thanks anyway !

Comment: are you heating it for its own sake or for humans?  Heating an insulator still seems counter-intuitive.  Seems like it would pass heat easier in the more compressed portions, creating hot spots.

Comment: I agree with Tiger Guy, I just don't see how this would work unless you had a hundred small heaters the size of a quarter that were controlled by a hundred thermostats located in a different layer. Perhaps 50 pounds of aluminum mesh could distribute the heat reasonable well, the way rebar does in concrete.

Comment: @electronpusher I will submit that ALL questions here are either homework (either for school or interest) or for help which could be provided by a consultant for big bucks.

Comment: Is "polyeurethane" a subtly different polymer from "polyurethane", or just a spelling mistake?  If the latter, polyurethane has a reputation for being flammable, so incorporating a heater in it may not be the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

My wife's Honda CR-V has heated seats.  Since the car is fairly new (and I want to stay married), I have not taken them apart to do a detailed investigation but my cursory examination does not show any individual heating elements.  The heaters appear to be distributed under the top layer of padding.

My suggestion is that you want to heat the people, not the mattress.  Put the heater under a thin layer of padding, just below the surface.

If you put the heater in the middle it will effectively be insulated (as observed in the comments). The good news is the heat has to go somewhere, so eventually the heat will find its way to the outside (the people).  The question comes up, how long will it take?  If you turn the heater on before going to bed and it starts to get warm eight hours later, that is of limited value.

You have to keep the heater from getting too hot so you will have to put a thermostat sensor in the middle, along with the heater.  Since the heating elements will be distributed and all insulated similarly, they will start at about the same temperature.  If somebody sits on the mattress, they will be closer to the heater and will feel warm.  A problem occurs if they sit near the thermostat and draw heat away so the rest of the heaters may get overly hot.

Electric blankets deal with a similar issue by having an external thermostat.  I don't know if they still do it this way but I've seen a unit that had the thermostat in a box that had similar thermal characteristics to the blanket on the bed.  As the room got colder, the blanket put out more heat.  If you put a second layer on top or piled the blanket up at the foot of the bed, all bets were off.  I believe there were over-temperature sensors distributed in the blanket so deal with cases like this but I don't know the details.